# Can I get the Contents in Android System's Back Stack?

Tags: android, stack

Can I get the Contents in Android System's Back Stack so I can print it out in my app coding?Is it possible?and How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. You can use `adb shell dumpsys activity` to see the current activity state and stack, but that's just a debugging tool. You shouldn't rely on its output or use it in your app.

Comment: Is't there a method like "activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()" to get that list or something like that?

Comment: You can get running tasks with this but it only gives you the top activity for each task: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)